# Pre and post increment operators in different classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to create traits that overload operators, to avoid code duplication. But when I try to put pre and post increment operators in different classes the compiler gives me an error: "operator ++ is ambiguous" Code:

```
class A
{
    public: 
    A& operator++(){return *this;}
};

class B
{
    public:
    B operator++(int){return *this;}        
};

class C:public A, public B
{
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c++;
    ++c;
}
```

In my case it is possible to inherit B from A, but then the compiler can't find the post-increment operator. Why does this happen, and what is the correct way?

Comment: Clang accepts the code. GCC bug?

Comment: If B inherits from A, then what you see in that case is *name hiding*.

Comment: @immibis Thank you, after googling I've added `using A::operator++;` to the `B` class and it worked.

Comment: @Brian It seems so. All versions of gcc at gcc.goodbolt refuse to compile this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC rejects the code, because it first performs name lookup without considering the argument lists, and the name is found in two base classes. Clang accepts the code, but this is caused by a bug.

The solution is to add `using` and create a separate class which inherits from A and B, and then inherit C from that class.

```
class A
{
    public: 
    A& operator++(){return *this;}
};

class B
{
    public:
    B operator++(int){return *this;}        
};

class AAndB:public A, public B
{
    public:
    using A::operator++;
    using B::operator++;
};

class C:public AAndB
{
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c++;
    ++c;
}
```